# Next-auth session doesn't update until I refresh the page or navigate to another page

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

So, I'm building an app with Next.js 13 and Next-auth and I have credential authentication (MongoDb and prisma). For example if the user is authenticated I navigate to /teach which is protected page. But when I click sign out the page doesn't say you don't have access to this page, but If I refresh the page or navigate to another page or come back, it works. Same for sign out button, if I refresh the page I see the sign out button but otherwise, after signing in, I don't see sign out until I refresh.

I'm not sure if there is a workaround and official solution for this, but I'd be grateful if you assist me.

[image]

I tried several ways, to refresh page on mount e.g but couldn't fix.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Answer (score 1):

nextauth credentials authentication doesn't do a callback refresh as the oauth providers, as a workaround, instead of checking session via server-side `getServerSession()` method, you can call client-side `useSession()` and reload the login page like below:

```
  const { data: session } = useSession()
  if (session) router.reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem. I did:

```
<button onClick={logOut}>SignOut</button>
```

My logout function:

```
 async function logOut(){
    await signOut();
    location.reload()
}
```

I read that the default behavior of the signOut() function was to refresh the page.
signOut by nextAuth is not doing that. So I think this is a bug in nextAuth. So I just forced the page to reload after signing out and this worked for me.
Cheers!